# Representation of GL(V) on Tensor Product of V with Dual

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

There is a question in Jacobson that I am having some trouble with (BA II, 5.1.3). The question asks:

> Let $\iota$ denote the identity map of $GL(V)$. This is a representation of $GL(V)$ acting on $V$. Consider the representation $\iota^{\ast}\otimes \iota$ acting on $V^{\ast}\bigotimes V$. Show that the set of vectors $c\in V^{\ast}\bigotimes V$ such that $(\iota^{\ast}\otimes \iota)(a)c = c$ for all $a\in GL(V)$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $V^{\ast}\bigotimes V$. Find a non-zero vector in this space.

I am having trouble with this. I don't know what $\iota^\ast$ would be (I am guessing it would map the endomorphism to that which acts in the same way on the dual basis). I can see that this is a one-dimensional subspace but I don't know how to find any nonzero vectors.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\iota^{\ast}$, written in terms of matrices, sends an element of $GL(V)$ to its inverse transpose.

Comment: So $\iota^\ast (a) = (a^{-1})^t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual pairing $V^{\ast}\otimes V\to k$ (given by $\varphi\otimes u\mapsto \varphi(u)$) bulks up to a map

$$ V^{\ast}\otimes V\otimes V\to V: (\varphi,v,u)\mapsto \varphi(u)v, $$

and so every element of $V^{\ast}\otimes V$ may be interpreted as a linear operator on $V$. In other words, this creates a linear map $V^{\ast}\otimes V\to\mathrm{End}(V)$, in  which $\varphi\otimes v$ acts as a linear operator via the formula $(\varphi\otimes v)(u)=\varphi(u)v$. One checks this is an isomorphism with bases and dimensions.

The dual action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ on $V^{\ast}$ is defined so as to make $V^{\ast}\otimes V\to\mathrm{End}(V)$ a $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-equivariant map, where $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ acts on $\mathrm{End}(V)$ by conjugation. Thus, if $\varphi\in V^\ast$ and $g\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $u\in V$ we have $(g\cdot \varphi)(u)=\varphi(g^{-1}u)$.

One can also call this the contragredient action. If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then it acts on the function space $Y^X$ via $(g\cdot f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$. One can interpret this as "translating the graph of $f$ along the domain by $g$," as I explain in more detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2120290/296782).

This converts your problem to talking about $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-invariant elements of $\mathrm{End}(V)$, or equivalently its center, which you should know is $k\cdot I_V$. In order to write these as elements of $V^{\ast}\otimes V$ you'll have to invoke bases and dual bases (I don't know of a way around this).

Comment: Thanks, so are you saying that the representation in question works something like this? (See below)
$(\iota^\ast \otimes \iota)(a)(u_i^\ast \otimes u_j) = (u_i^\ast \circ a^{-1} \otimes a(u_j))$

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: From what I've read about this problem in other stackexchange questions, the statement you made in the first para required finiteness of dimensionality, does this also hold for infinite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: Nope. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Then how can this be applied in the infinite dimensional case since the problem doesn't assume finiteness of dimension?

Comment: Also, the center doesn't seem to be invariant under multiplication by invertible matrices, for example when we take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, letting $P\neq 1$ be the only other permutation matrix, $P(k\cdot I_V)= k \cdot P \neq k\cdot I_V$ for each $k\in \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: I think such a space of invariant matrices will at least have to be non-invertible because the determinant should not change when multiplied by $GL(V)$ matrices (which are bound to have nonzero determinant).

Comment: (1) Your problem must assume finite-dimensionality. If $V$ has infinite dimension, then there are no nonzero $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-invariant elements of $V^{\ast}\otimes V$. (I am interpreting $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ as the group of all invertible linear operators, correct me if I'm wrong.) (2) Indeed, the center of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is not invariant under left multiplication by $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, which is irrelevant because like I said $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is acting on $\mathrm{End}(V)$ by conjugation, not left multiplication.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are $G$-sets then a function $f:X\to Y$ is $G$-equivariant if $f(gx)=gf(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $g\in G$. (Saying $X$ is a $G$-set is another way of saying a group $G$ acts on a set $X$.)

Comment: Okay thank you, I got it now.